# Several modified files. Commit only fileA in branchA, fileB in branchB,

Tags: git

I have a project on which I am working. Everytime a I want to create a new feature, I branch from its main branch and create a new one, called FeatureX, which I will later merge into the main.

Let's suppose I created a branch called featureA, and there I ended up modifying featureA (which is in fileA.py) and also modifying featureB (which is in fileB.py).

Being on branchA, if commit as I usually do, I would include the changes done in fileB in branchA, which I don't want. I want to commit tha changes done in fileA in branchA and the changes done in fileB in branchB.

How could I, being in branchA, commit only the change done in fileA.py, then checkout to branchB and commit there only the change made to fileB.py?

Edit:

I didn't specify this in my original message and maybe I should clarify it: fileA and fileB exist in both branches (branchA and branchB).

However, when I commit in branchA, I want to commit only the changes done in fileA, and leave fileB unmodified. Then checkout to branchB and commit only the changes done to fileB, leaving its version of fileA intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're on the right branch for feature A:

```
git checkout featureA
```

add the changes and commit them

```bsh
git add fileA.py  # use correct path to the file, of course
git commit -m "Glorious updates to fileA"
```

---

Now, to take your change to `fileB.py` along to the other feature branch, there's an easy and a more complicated case.

**Easy case: `fileB.py` does not differ between branches**

Change to the other branch, and do the same

```bsh
git checkout featureB
git add fileB.py
git commit -m "Fabulous bugfixes to fileB"
```

**(Slightly) More complicated case: `fileB.py` differs**

If `fileB.py` differs, the checkout for `featureB` will fail (Git will abort the checkout with a message that uncommitted changes would be overwritten). So you can just try the checkout, *you will not lose changes unless you use the `-f/--force` switch or use something else like `git clean`*. You will get this error:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    fileB.py
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

You will have to stash your changed for a moment. Like this:

```bsh
git stash # will save all uncommitted changed into a temporary space
git checkout featureB
git stash pop # will try to apply your saved changes; there may be a conflicts
    # if there are conflicts (Git will tell you), go through normal  resolution
git add fileB.py
git commit -m "Incandescent stash of bugfixes to fileB"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nevik. I have edited my original message because I am not sure if your answer would work if both files already existed in both branches but I only want to update fileA in branch A and fileB in branchB. Would it?

Comment: Just updated my answer to include the problem case as well :)

Comment: Thank you very much Nevik once again. Your answer was very helpful!